# Powerbi Date table makes all related visuals run very slow

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

The following is in direct query mode:

I have a date/time table that 10 separate queries have a relationship to. All data is from the current day. The date/time table just returns all times on 15 minute intervals up to the current timestamp. This works fine.

I have about 10+ queries that each have a record from whateever the latest 15 minute interval time stamp was. Each of these queries has a relationship to the date/time table.

I am wondering why any visual that uses the date/time table is incredibly slow. Say I have a visual that shows the timestamps on the x axis, and the data on a line (E.g. at 3:45 I had 10 records. At 4 I had 5 records. At 4:15 I had 1 record). If I use the date/time table time on the x axis, it is very slow. If I use the timestamp from the query on the x axis, it is very fast.

Is it doing something with all of the related queries? Only about 2-3 of them should actually be running at any given time based on what page I am on.

Comment: can you post a shot of the data model?

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the data model. Please post a shot or explain how are the table connected. I would also ask: why do you need the time dimension? What type of extra value does it offer?

Comment: Its always good to have a date table but using your date table as your fact table may be causing performance issues.

Comment: Use [All Queries Trace](https://daxstudio.org/documentation/features/all-queries-trace/) feature of [DAX Studio](https://daxstudio.org/) to see what is happening.

Comment: My date/time table is in the center. All of my other queries each have the same date/time column used to create a many to one relationship to the date/time table. Note this works fine in import. Just not direct query. And it is not an issue of slow sql